# n x n dataframe to a matrix (.as_matrix will be removed in a future version)

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'From':['a','b','c','a','d'], 'To':['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'], 'Rates':[1e-4, 2.3e-2, 1e-2, 100, 70]})

df2 = df.pivot(index="From", columns="To", values="Rates")

full_index = df2.index.union(df2.columns)

df2 = df2.reindex(labels=full_index, axis=0).reindex(labels=full_index, axis=1).fillna(0.0)

df2
Out[21]: 
      a       b      c      d     e
a  0.00  0.0001  0.000  100.0   0.0
b  0.00  0.0000  0.023    0.0   0.0
c  0.01  0.0000  0.000    0.0   0.0
d  0.00  0.0000  0.000    0.0  70.0
e  0.00  0.0000  0.000    0.0   0.0
```

I have to convert `df2` into a matrix for matrix multiplication.

```
df2.as_matrix()
__main__:1: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
Out[22]: 
array([[0.0e+00, 1.0e-04, 0.0e+00, 1.0e+02, 0.0e+00],
       [0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 2.3e-02, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00],
       [1.0e-02, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00],
       [0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 7.0e+01],
       [0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00]])
```

Is there another way to convert a n x n dataframe into a matrix that will also work in the future? Is `df2.to_numpy()` the same?

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but from the warning: "...Use .values instead." seems pretty clear.

Comment: Shoot, you are right. I was trying .values() instead of .values. Thanks.

Comment: You can do matrix multiplication in pandas via `df_LHS.dot(df_RHS)`.